# Titanium including a model for joli.js

Tags: ios, database, titanium, titanium-alloy

I've got a Titanium Mobile App, using the Alloy framework.

In the default structure you get folders called

Controllers,
Models,
Styles, Views

I'm using Joli.js ( https://github.com/xavierlacot/joli.js/ ) for the database interaction.

However Joli has you defining your model, which is absolutely fine, however in the example and documents it shows having all of your models/tables in 1 file, inside /lib directory.

I want to keep it as clean/obvious as possible for new devs so trying to figure out how to allow it to load the model.js files from inside the /models directory.

So far I've attempted this concept.

**/app/alloy.js**

```
    app = {};
    app.init = function{
       app.setupDB();
    };

    app.setupDB = function(){

         var models = ['organisations'];

         _.each(models, function(model){
            DB.tables[model] = require('/models/' + model);   
         });

        DB.models.initialize();
    };

    app.init();
```

**/app/models/organisations.js**

```
var m = {};

m.table = 'organisations';

m.columns = {
    Id: 'INTEGER PRIMARY',
    Name: 'TEXT',
    Contact: 'TEXT'
};

alert('heyheyhey');

module.exports = new DB.model( m );
```

However the model doesnt auto-load, So I tried adding the setupDB function to include the files.

I've tried this with both require, and Ti.include.

They both fire up errors similar to

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: /models/organisations
```

To me it seems that it cannot find the models/ directory.

If anybody knows how to load files manually from the /models/ directory in a titanium alloy project, then it would be much appreciated.